# How to find the changes between two arrays of objects (src and update), and apply the changes to the src array?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays `src` and `update`. Both contain objects. Incoming JSON from an API, the objects in the arrays follow the same structure (see below).

I want to compare `src` against `update` and add/remove/update items in `src` that have represented changes in `update`.

My current process involves iterating both arrays and comparing items using `JSON.stringify()`, doing multiple passes. Pass one to add, pass two to delete, and pass three to detect changes for replacement (I replace the entire object rather than the fields).

Is there an easier/better way?

Is there a generic utility to help facilitate for this or must I write my own diff detection system?

EDIT: The objects inside the arrays look like (but not limited to):

```
[
    {
        id: String,
        summary: String,
        updates: [
            {
                date: String,
                title: String
            },
            { Repeated }
        ]
    },
    { Repeated }
]
```

Comment: I usually use lodash `_.isEqual` it does deep object comparision.

Answer (score 1):

As Ali pointed out lodash `_.isEqual` is a good utility method for this.

Check out https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual

Lodash is really good for helper functions and dealing with data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly both your 'updates' and 'src' array have the same structure - objects with two properties, 'date' and 'title'.  You can compare them with nested loops.  For example, something like this might be helpful...

```
updates.forEach(function(u) {
    src.forEach(function(s) {
        if (s.date === u.date && s.title === u.title) {
            // You have a match
        }
    });
});
```

I presume you want to identify partial matches, so you can add/replace the if-condition in the inner loop and amend the src array accordingly...

```
if (s.date === u.date && s.title !== u.title) {
    // same date, different title, so...
    // change the title of the current
    // item from the 'src' array;
    s.title = u.title;
}
```

Or use if-else-if conditions as needed.  Regardless, although it's not quite clear from your question which array should be the outer-loop and which should be the inner, the nested 'forEach' loops above will compare each item in the 'updates' array against every item in the 'src' array.

I hope that helped.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that's correct. So essentially, I would need to have a unique process for combining packages of data, based on the data itself?

Comment: @DavidAlsh The demo shows how you can deal with two arrays with the same data structure, but if you're dealing with arrays inside arrays ... inside arrays ... your can continue the principle to access and compare data with loops inside loops ... inside loops ... and down into the depths as needed. ;) And you can always farm the matches out to special functions to do the actual processing, just to keep things tidy and refactorable etc.